# Line between Two GeoPoints in Google map in android?

Tags: android

Hi I want to draw a line between 2 GeoPoints on Google map in android.Your help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

[Connect points on map with lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903004/connect-points-on-map-with-lines/4903756#4903756)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom overlay, override the draw method and draw the line between the two points.

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow){
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        path = new Path();
        Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
        proj.toPixels(gp1, p1);
        proj.toPixels(gp2, p2);
        path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);
        canvas.drawPath(path, somePaintObject);
}
```